# C++ Member-wise initialization, copy initialization and default initialization

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, initialization

From the book, The C++ Programming Language, 4th edition, 
Section "17.3.1 Initialization Without Constructors", Page 489

The marked line in the example from the book fails to compile with this error -

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 ch17_pg489.cpp
ch17_pg489.cpp: In function 'int main()':
ch17_pg489.cpp:32:34: error: could not convert 's9' from 'Work' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'
      Work currently_playing { s9 }; // copy initialization
```

I have Cygwin

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (tdm64-2) 4.8.1
```

To quote from the text from the aforementioned section,

```
we can initialize objects of a class for which we have not defined a constructor using
• memberwise initialization,
• copy initialization, or
• default initialization (without an initializer or with an empty initializer list).


#include <iostream>

struct Work {
    std::string author;
    std::string name;
    int year;
};

int main() {

    Work s9 { "Beethoven",
    "Symphony No. 9 in D minor, Op. 125; Choral",
    1824
    }; //memberwise initialization

/* 
    // This correctly prints the respective fields
    std::cout << s9.author << " | " 
                        << s9.name << " | "
                        << s9.year << std::endl;
*/

  // Fails to compile
    Work currently_playing { s9 }; // copy initialization

    Work none {}; // default initialization

    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding, either copy initialization would be provided by the default copy constructor generated by the compiler Or it would be simply a member wise copy (assigning one struct to another, as in C). So the program should have compiled here.

Or is this the compiler quirk??

Any explanations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see under the errata for the 4th edition

http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html

> People have pointed out that the {} doesn't work for copy
>   construction:
>
> ```
> X x1 {2};     // construct from integer (assume suitable constructor)
> X x2 {x1};        // copy construction: fails on GCC 4.8 and Clang 3.2
> ```
>
> I know that. It's a bug in the standard. Fixed for C++14. For now use
>   one of the traditional notations:
>
> ```
> X x3(x1);     // copy construction
> X x4 = x1;        // copy construction
> ```

It's [fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51747) for GCC 4.10

[Here's](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1467) the defect report itself.

Comment: Lol. I had visited the errata page of the site before posting the question. Had also seen what you have pasted here. Still my eyes failed to pick this line - "// copy construction: fails on GCC 4.8 and Clang 3.2" .. See I have even given my compiler version in the question :) Thanks for the additional info about fix in GCC 4.10 .. Indeed its a compiler quirk.

Comment: @nightlytrails It's a defect in the standard, not the compiler.

Comment: Again, that "bug in standard" is explicitly mentioned in the errata. Probably time for me to take a nap and rest my tired eyes :-)

Comment: @nightlytrails No worries, happens to everyone.